# Alternative to SharePoint Remote Event Receiver

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have been investigating a problem for some time in which a Remote Event Receiver I had written for an Azure hosted app was sporadically not taking effect (less than 1% of the time). I put in some serious logging but couldn't identify the issue, as far as I could tell the remote receiver wasn't being called by some actions that should have triggered it. I eventually escalated the problem to Microsoft and after some time their response was effectively that they can't guarantee the event receiver will trigger with 100% reliability.

So what I'm looking for is any suggestions on ways to improve reliability of a RER or alternatives that can be used to trigger an event each time an item is added or updated to a list in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever first guided you toward using Remote Event Receivers should have indicated that they're not guaranteed to fire, so they're only suited for non-critical notifications and user interface improvements (like refreshing a view when an item is added to a list).

To truly guarantee the execution of some action when items are added or updated in a list, your two best options are **workflows** and server-side **event receivers**.

Since it sounds like your environment is cloud-hosted, you are likely restricted to using workflows (event receivers require deployment of custom farm solutions).

For reference on how to create a workflow, see Microsoft's documentation entitled "[Creating a workflow by using SharePoint Designer 2013 and the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx)".

Comment: Hi Thriggle, thank you for your answer. I actually came in part way through this project which had been started using RER and assumed the research had already been done on them.

You are correct that this is a cloud-hosted app so server-side event receivers aren't feasible (I should have noted that in the question).

It looks like workflows are the only guaranteed way to proceed with this then, I need to look into ways to automate deploying them as quite a few will need developing.